# I am using selenium module for automation. I am giving input data and results page loaded in separate tab. I want to save results page in html format

Tags: python, shell

I want to save the child window in the HTML file.

In the first window, I am clicking on the button to show results on a new page. It will load a new tab, and I want to save the new opened results tab in the Html file. Somehow it is saving the first that is parent page, not the child page.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_class_name('inlineLabel')).click().perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('b1')).click().perform()

time.sleep(60)
path = "/home/pallavi/Pallavi/python_practice/code_primer_design"
file_name = "res.html"
completeName = os.path.join(path,file_name)
file_object = open(completeName, "w")
html = driver.page_source
file_object.write(html)
```

It is saving the parent window in Html. I want to save the child window in Html format.